# How to force JavaFX application close request programmatically

Tags: javafx

I have been using `javafx.stage.Window.setOnCloseRequest(EventHandler<WindowEvent> arg0)` to run some code as I close my application. Now I would like to force a close request in my code, so this very same algorithm is run.

I tried `stage.close()`, `Platform.exit()` and `System.exit()` to no avail; they all close the application, but directly. Is there a smooth way to do this without making a [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) press `Alt + F4`? (I can also imagine making a function out of the algorithm and calling it in `setOnCloseRequest()` and wherever else I might need it).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can get the event handler from the stage and invoke it.

```
stage.getOnCloseRequest()
    .handle(
        new WindowEvent(
            stage,
            WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST
        )
    )
```

But probably what you want to do is not just invoke your custom close request handler function, but rather fire a close request event which will run your handler and any other close event handlers for the window, (so, by default it will also close the window).

```
stage.fireEvent(
    new WindowEvent(
        stage,
        WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST
    )
)
```

*Sample App*

Run the sample below (Java 8) to see the difference between the behavior of the two approaches:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

public class CloseMonitor extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(
                event -> System.out.println("Close Requested")
        );

        Button handleClose = new Button("Handle Close Request");
        handleClose.setOnAction(
                event -> stage.getOnCloseRequest()
                        .handle(
                                new WindowEvent(
                                        stage,
                                        WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST
                                )
                        )
        );
        handleClose.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        Button fireClose = new Button("Fire Close Request");
        fireClose.setOnAction(
                event -> stage.fireEvent(
                        new WindowEvent(
                                stage,
                                WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST
                        )
                )
        );
        fireClose.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        stage.setScene(
                new Scene(
                        new VBox(
                                10,
                                handleClose,
                                fireClose    
                        )
                )
        );
        stage.show();
        stage.sizeToScene();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: `fireEvent()` was exactly what I was looking for.